# Wifi Conection problem my Lenovo 59-442243 15.6-inch Laptop (Core i3 4030U/4GB/1TB/DOS/Integrated Graphics Processor

Tags: laptop, lenovo

Wifi doesn't work on ubuntu but on windows does.

```
bnogroups@bnogroups:~$ lspci | grep -i wireless
bnogroups@bnogroups:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

bnogroups@bnogroups:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Then reboot.

---

This will install a proprietary driver for your wifi card (that I guess that is a Broadcom B43) If this doesn't work, I'll ask you for more data.

Comment: Please give some additional explanations about what the package you want to install does. Your answer is a bit short...